# Date and References in the footer of the first page of a report

Tags: footnotes, report, date

I am writing a report in which i need to write date in the footer. **But only in the first page of the report**. How do I write date in footer? Also I need to write the references there in the footer of the first page.

like:

References:

1.The first one
2.The second one

12/06/2021

Comment: You can do a lot with fancy, but you need to provide an MWE and it is better to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be in the footer or just at the bottom of the text? If the latter you could use a `figure` (or `table`) environment placed at the bottom of the text holding the information.

```
% repfootprob.tex  SE 600913
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
FIRST PAGE.

\begin{figure}[b]
References:

1. The first one 2. The second one

12/06/2021
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]